# How to apply a function to a column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

For a given string like `1_2_5` i need to obtain the sum of values which is `1+2+5 = 8` and then specify if it is greater than `6`

I have the below code which works well

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.sum( list( map( float, "1_2_5".split("_"))))> 6
```

Now imagine i have the a dataframe with the same strings

```
dict = {"State":["0_0_1","4_0_0","4_0_3"]}
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dict)
```

i need to apply the same logic to a column (`State`). Here is my code:

```
np.sum( list( map( float, dt["State"].apply(lambda x: x.split("_")))))> 6
```

but it complains with:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use `apply()` for this:

```
>>> [sum(map(float, s.split('_'))) for s in dt.State]
[1.0, 4.0, 7.0]
```

This computes a separate sum for each row.  If you need the overall sum:

```
>>> sum(sum(map(float, s.split('_'))) for s in dt.State)
12.0
```

Comparing that to 6 is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this monstrous oneliner?

```
>>> df['State'].apply(lambda x: sum(float(i) for i in x.split('_')) > 6).tolist()
[False, False, True]
```

Comment: Add least add some lines to it. Otherwise it is unlikely to be understood in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Jan dunno, I think it's readable enough and is self-explanatory, no? (ټ)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like good example for combination of `eval` and `apply`

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dict = {"State":["0_0_1","4_0_0","4_0_3"]}
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dict)

dt["State"].apply(lambda x: eval(x.replace("_", "+"))>6)
```

And output:

```py
0    False
1    False                                                  
2     True                                                  
Name: State, dtype: bool                                    
[Program finished]
```